# NTLM SoapClient

Tags: php, soap-client, ntlm

I have been looking around for a while (including existing questions and github projects) but all seem to fail in my situation:

a Soap service behind an NTLM authentication code works using PHP5.5 (with streamwrappers and extensions) but fails to even construct in PHP7.3? (or even .1/.2/.3)

The `url_stat` is hit on the stream_wrapper (and returns the size of the buffer) after succesfully retrieving the WSDL, but then still the \SoapClient::__construct()-call fails... ?

I've been looking allover the interwebs, and forums but none of the available code seems to work? (and trying to convert to 'basic auth', since we're hitting it over SSL anyway, is somehow difficult for the client to achieve)